# Calculated member to get dimension value in previous year

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I am new to BI and need help to create a calculated member.

I have a cube with following dimension and measure:

- Dimension tables: 
  **Dim_Time** (Year, Month, Day)
- **Dim_MyValueCollection**: DataType with data types having values 'Gross Paid Claims' and 'Gross Written Premiums'
- Measure:
  FactTable.Value

I need to create a calculated member on **Dim_MyValueCollection.DataType** to represent the difference of 'Gross Written Premiums' values in current and previous year.

Comment: (upped your question as I'm interested to try and help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data from a previous period in `mdx` you can use these functions:

`Lag`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144866.aspx

`ParallelPeriod`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145500.aspx

Have you attempted any `mdx` ?

---

**Edit**

Here is a general `tuple` for the change in `Gross Written Premiums` since the same period in the previous year. I've guessed the names of your dimensions because you have not supplied any sample `mdx`:

```
([Time].CURRENTMEMBER, [Measures].[Gross Written Premiums]) 
-
(PARALLELPERIOD(Year,1,[Time].CURRENTMEMBER), [Measures].[Gross Written Premiums])
```

Comment: I know very little MDX but don't know how to write the query.

Comment: Where is the `mdx` going? In the cube script, or in a third party tool?

Comment: try writing some `mdx` in `SSMS` and then paste into your question for us to play with

Comment: Tried the following to get values from last year but got 'parallelperiod function expects a level expression at level 1' error


(PARALLELPERIOD([Dim_Time].[Year], 1, [Dim_Time].[Year].CURRENTMEMBER), [Dim_MyValueCollection].[Data Type].&[Gross Written Premiums])

Comment: is `[Dim_Time].[Year]` a level in your cube?! or in your cube is the level identified like this `[Dim_Time].[Year].[Year]`. Also I suspect you need to change this `[Dim_Time].[Year].CURRENTMEMBER` to this `[Dim_Time].CURRENTMEMBER`.

Comment: [Dim_Time].[Year].[Year] is the level but when I try it I get an error with no further info!

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at Analysis services browser which was throwing exceptions. Tried it in SSMS and works!